# difference between experience of and experience

Tags: vocabulary

Would you show me which one is correct, as I have seen both experience of +an ing verb and experience +an ing verb in dictionaries?

Dictionaries' example: It was an experience being involved in making a television program

His peers, with whom he shares the common experience of being black in a white society

My example: It was an experience of being involved in making a television program

My examples: ... as a person who has five years experience heading this institute...

.... as a person who has five years experience of heading this institute...

Comment: Experience in, (not of).

Answer (score 1):

> I had the **experience of** going skydiving yesterday.

This might not be the best example but I think you get the idea. In this case the meaning is a specific experience (something that happened to you that you will remember).

> She is a person who has five years experience heading this institute.

This is like your example. Here **experience** is a general term for a range of things you learned over time.

Comment: Considering my original question, would you please give me a more accurate answer, and answer my original question? many thanks

Comment: @nima_persian User3169's answer is a good explanation of the two uses you asked about.  Specifically for your first example, it's difficult to say without further context.  In your second example, you would either omit "of" or use "in" instead.